# Replace substring with conditions

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to search through an Excel file with strings in column A, and replace a part of the string if a couple of conditions pass.

Logically: `if NAME and CODE(A) or CODE(B) exist in string then replace NAME`

Example: `NAME = child1in  CODE(A) = csus  CODE(B) = mfus`

Note: there are several names that need to be replaced but the codes are the same
TIA!

Before: 
**child1in**,"dv","","**csus**","AVU","06212017","06212017","","1","","","caus","$cash","","","","","598.5","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","7667079","","48","","","n","y","","","","","","","","","","","","",""

After:
**child1**,"dv","","csus","AVU","06212017","06212017","","1","","","caus","$cash","","","","","598.5","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","7667079","","48","","","n","y","","","","","","","","","","","","",""

Here is my code:

---

```
`Sub replacement_TEST()

Dim rows As Integer
Dim acct1 As String
Dim eqcode As String

rows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.rows.Count

For i = 1 To rows

acct1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).value
eqcode = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4).value

If acct1 = "child1in" And (eqcode = "csus" Or eqcode = "mfus") Then
                             acct1 = Replace(acct1, "child1in", "child1")
ElseIf acct1 = "wstre2in" And (eqcode = "csus" Or eqcode = "mfus") Then
                             acct1 = Replace(acct1, "wstre2in", "wstre2lv")
ElseIf acct1 = "wstrebin" And (eqcode = "csus" Or eqcode = "mfus") Then
                             acct1 = Replace(acct1, "wstrebin", "wstrebal")
ElseIf acct1 = "lrcfbag" And (eqcode = "csus" Or eqcode = "mfus") Then
                             acct1 = Replace(acct1, "lrcfbag", "lrcfbal")
ElseIf acct1 = "wstpsbst" And (eqcode = "csus" Or eqcode = "mfus") Then
                             acct1 = Replace(acct1, "wstpsbst", "wstpsbal")

                End If

                    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).value = acct1

        Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to explain how your code doesn't work. Does it error - if so where - or just not do what you want?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: It's difficult to make sense of what you're doing here, as you're hard-coding `eqcode` and `acct1`: it's not clear what you want to do in the following If block, since only the first check will ever pass...  It would help to show examples of "before" and "after" data.

Comment: Hi srgomez is this all your code cause it looks to me that you have an extra 'End If' and your missing a 'Next i' statement.

Comment: could be?  i am very new to vba! -  i explained that a bit but the mod deleted i guess.

Comment: hi, @MikePowell thanks for your comments.  i have posted some revised code with before and after. if you have any advice it would be greatly appreciated as the code does not work - i apologize for not explaining more but i am new to vba.  thank you for your patience!

Comment: hi, @TimWilliams thanks for your comments. i have posted some revised code with before and after. if you have any advice it would be greatly appreciated as the code does not work - i apologize for not explaining more but i am new to vba. thank you for your patience!

Comment: Hi srgomez,    I have tried your revised code and it worked for me. Are you still having trouble with it?

Comment: @mikepowell yes i got it to work! thanks for your attention! i have an added question on how i can make a tweak to it, see below to tim  - TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work.  You could more-easily mange this if you put your find/replace pairs on a worksheet and used that in a VLOOKUP.

```
Sub replacement_TEST()

    Dim rows As Long, i As Long, n As Long
    Dim acct1 As String
    Dim eqcode As String
    Dim sht As Worksheet, arrFind, arrRepl, m

    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    rows = sht.UsedRange.rows.Count

    'arrays of matching find/replace values
    arrFind = Array("child1in", "wstre2in", "wstrebin", "lrcfbag", "wstpsbst")
    arrRepl = Array("child1", "wstre2lv", "wstrebal", "lrcfbal", "wstpsbal")

    For i = 1 To rows
        acct1 = sht.Cells(i, 1).Value
        eqcode = sht.Cells(i, 4).Value

        If eqcode = "csus" Or eqcode = "mfus" Then
            m = Application.Match(acct1, arrFind, 0) '<< any match ?
            If Not IsError(m) Then
                sht.Cells(i, 1).Value = arrRepl(m - 1) 'm is 1-based...
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: THANKS!   - 1 more question, if all the data (including eqcode) was in column A (like a .csv) and not in 4th column - how would you modify the above to accomplish the same goal? - i tried to simply change the 4 to a 1 but that didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure this is what you're looking for, but it certainly is a starting point. Modify it as required to fit your needs.

```
Sub replacement_TEST()

    Dim r As Range, c As Range, values As Variant
    Set r = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1))

    For Each c In r
        'Split comma separated values
        values = Split(c.Value, ",")

        'According to the screenshot provided, the index of "eqcode" is 3
        'and the "acct1" is 0
        If values(3) = "csus" Or values(3) = "mfus" Then
            Select Case values(0)
                Case "child1in":
                    c.Value = Replace(c.Value, values(0), "child1")

                Case "wstre2in":
                    c.Value = Replace(c.Value, values(0), "wstre2lv")

                Case "wstrebin":
                    c.Value = Replace(c.Value, values(0), "wstrebal")

                Case "lrcfbag":
                    c.Value = Replace(c.Value, values(0), "lrcfbal")

                Case "wstpsbst":
                    c.Value = Replace(c.Value, values(0), "wstpsbal")

                Case Else:
                    'do nothing
            End Select
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks @Kostas for your help, though it didnt work..  i have updated my version of the code (also still doesnt work)  any advice?

Comment: It's probably due to the quotes `"` around the value? Try a `Debug.Print values(3)` to see if the quotes are included in the string.

Comment: i got a compile error: sub or function not defined @kostas k